# How do I set a default value to optional parameter in my struct model class in Swft?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, jsondecoder

I'm working with a model -

```
struct Planet : Codable {
    var name : String
    var distance : Int
    var isSelected : Bool?
}
```

The data is being fetched from the server and only name and distance are provided by the server. I have added isSelected to keep track of the item being selected.

I'm using JSDecoder class to parse this data.

I tried using `var isSelected : Bool ?? false` but it gives compiler error.

Since the isSelected value is not provided by server, is there any way I can set the default value false to this?

Comment: `var isSelected: Bool? = false`

Comment: My suspicion is that adding an `isSelected` property is a bad approach anyway. Remember that structs are copy on write. You may be better off with some other data structure to track selection; a `Set<Planet>` for example

Comment: @the4kman when decoding, the value will be overwritten with `nil`.